# Native creation and connection of TCP socket, freezes app when server is not available

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I'm stucking in one problem never experienced before.
Application uses native code to create **TCP socket** and **connect** to the remote server through Wi-Fi. If server is already **down**, but I try to connect to it by ip and port(doing by native code) android application **freezes**. I tried to connect by calling that native method through AsyncTask, Thread no luck. Also by killing thread I could not prevent app freezing.

Any suggestion would be kindly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you post some code.  If you had successfully threaded it off or submitted it as async then the app would not freeze.

Comment: I'm just calling native connect and disconnect api's. When I programmatically disabled and enabled Wi-Fi app does not freeze. I think that there is some lock option of socket